# Sequelize ORM: Cyclic dependency found

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use the Mocha testing suite to test my Node.JS code. As ORM layer to connect to the database I am using Sequelize.

Running Mocha throws the error "Cyclic dependency found". This because of the following:

Membership model

```
...
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    Membership.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'UserId'});
  }
},
...
```

User model

```
...
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    UserProfile.hasOne(models.Membership, {foreignKey: 'UserId'});
  }
},
...
```

Any ideas on how to solve this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with mocha, and all to do with sequelize. You need to remove one of the associations, you don't need both of them, sequelize will know how your models relate to one another.